# DTTableViewmanager: Cell mapping is missing for model

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using a [DTTableViewManager](https://cocoapods.org/pods/DTTableViewManager) for my `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` contained within.

My View Controller only contains:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, DTTableViewManageable {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let users = ["Test User 1", "Test User 2"]

        manager.startManaging(withDelegate: self)
        manager.register(PersonsCell.self)
        manager.memoryStorage.addItem(users, toSection: 0)

    }

}
```

This is conform their Github [example](https://github.com/DenHeadless/DTTableViewManager/blob/master/Example/Example%20controllers/CustomViewsController.swift)

My `UITableViewCell` looks as follows:

```
class PersonsCell: UITableViewCell, ModelTransfer {

    func update(with model: String) {
        self.nameLabel = model        
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
}
```

This is also conform their [example](https://github.com/DenHeadless/DTTableViewManager/blob/master/Example/Cells/CustomStringCell.swift) on Github.

But still I'm getting this error:

> fatal error: Cell mapping is missing for model: ["Test User 1", "Test User 2"]: file ~~ ~/Pods/DTTableViewManager/Source/DTTableViewManager.swift, line 737

I have tried to find examples for people with similar problems but I could not find them.

Comment: Hey!

You should use `addItems` instead of `addItem` since you have an array of models, not a model.

Comment: @DenHeadless You are right! It works now.